# Regex percentage separated by comma

Tags: java, regex, numbers, validation

I've to create a regex with this rules:

1. Number are between 5-100
2. Number are separated by comma (55,70,90)
3. Number are unique in string

For example:

- 10,20,50 OK
- 10 ,20,50 NO (white space)
- 10,20,50, NO (final comma)
- 10,10,20 NO (unique)

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and why it has failed?

Comment: Well, numbers are between 5 and 100 and numbers are separated by a comma is possible, but the duplicate number thing is well outside the possibilities of regular expressions I think.

Comment: Is this homework? Does it have to be implemented entirely as a regex or can you use some Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may be possible to perform all checks with a regex, I think it's not the right tool for the job.

I would:

- Use a regex to verify the string is only numbers and commas: `^(?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+$`
- Use `split(',', $input)` to turn into array
- Loop over array and ensure numbers are between 5 - 100 (arithmetic comparison) and no duplicates (array comparison).

Comment: I've tried with String input = "40,50,80";
  String pattern = "/^[0-9,]+$/";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  System.out.println(m.matches()); but return always false!

Comment: +1 This solution is simple and easy to understand. I would improve the regex to make it numbers and commas, like `^(?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+$`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a job for regex, because you've got

1. a variable number of items in the list
2. restrictions on numbers (>5, <100) which are usually difficult to represent in a regular expression.

You can do this simply with a [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String arr[] = s.split(",");
for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  // apply your rules here
}
```

Comment: A regex could be used for validation. You're assuming the input is in a valid format, which according to the OP is not.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to question 1)

```
(?:[5-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)(?![0-9])
```

Number that is either between 5 and 9, between 10 and 99, or 100, not followed by a digit.